# Control the running number of Matlab simulations

Tags: matlab, process, controls

I have to make a total amount of simulations (e.g. NUM)
 with Matlab witch I run with the following line

```
./run.sh -d num
```

repeatedly, where num ( NUM = integer*num) indicates the number of new Matlabs. 
The same could happen with any other computing program in C or NS, etc.
The problem is that the computer where these processes run only admits a maximum number of Matlabs, e.g. MAX. 
I would like to keep track of the number of Matlabs running and when the maximum number is reduced to  (MAX-num), because 'num' has already finished, then run the next 'num' simulations of Matlab until the total NUM of simulations is completed.

To know the number of running processes I run the following script

```
ps axu |grep plopez|grep simulacion|grep MATLAB|awk '{ $2} END{print NR}'
```

which gives the total Matlabs running in this moment.

How could I make the whole set of simulations just from a single script?

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty way would be to divide your set of simulations into NUM subsets, then you can work sequentially on these subsets.

I used the following script to process some images. The folder structure was like this:

- CASE

  - 20p
  - 40p
  - 60p
  - 80p
  - 100p

So I entered the CASE folder in the Terminal and ran my script. This called sequentially matlab and ran the script "processImages" to produce some extract data.

The

```
list=$(ls | grep p)
```

is really some quick and dirty line of code. However, it worked in my case and might give you the hint to solve the problem.

Have a very nice day.

```
#!/bin/bash

list=$(ls | grep p)

echo $list

for d in $list
    do
        echo $d
        cd $d
        matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "processImages; exit"
        cd ..
done
```